# Symfony Doctrine Rename table used for ManyToMany

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine

I am working on a project with symfony 5.

I need to use an existing database with existing tables.
I have a problem when I create a ManyToMany relation. For example:
for a ManyToMany relation for entities post and tag, doctrine create a table named post_tag.

I need to rename this table to link_post_tag. I can rename it in the sql database (easy) but what do I need to modify in symfony to make it work. Because symfony is still looking for the post_tag table.

I have looked in the doctrine and symfony documentation but found nothing.

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

With `@ORM\JoinTable`. The Doctrine documentation explains it here : https://doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional

```php
/**
* Many Users have Many Groups.
* @var Collection<int, Group>
*/
#[JoinTable(name: 'users_groups')]
#[JoinColumn(name: 'user_id', referencedColumnName: 'id')]
#[InverseJoinColumn(name: 'group_id', referencedColumnName: 'id')]
#[ManyToMany(targetEntity: Group::class)]
private Collection $groups;
```